# Switching between HTTPS and HTTP when logging in or out

Tags: php, security, session

I have my sessions configured to only use cookies, and to use a separate cookie for encrypted connections:

```
// only allow cookie based sessions
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', TRUE);

// use a separate cookie for secure sessions
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    ini_set('session.cookie_secure', TRUE);
} else {
    ini_set('session.cookie_secure', FALSE);
}
$sess_prefix = ini_get('session.cookie_secure') ? 'SSL_' : '';
session_name($sess_prefix . 'PHPSESSID');

// start session
session_start();
```

All of the links on my site use relative paths. My question is, after a user is logged in how can I force all of the links to use HTTPS, and then go back to allowing HTTP after they logout?

I know I can force it on mandatory pages, for example:

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

But how would I handle conditional pages? When they're logged in I don't want to allow HTTP to be used at all.

Comment: I would use apache rules to send https requests to different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have authorization cookies that are not HTTPS-only then by the time they get to your server via `http` for you to redirect them to `https`, they might already have been compromised by a MITM, so the only cookies you can store on the HTTP version of the domain is a hint that there are valid login cookies for the HTTPS version of the site.

Since you can't authenticate an http request using credentials that don't appear with it, just have your credential checking code redirect to https when the user appears to be logged in.

To make links that lead to `http` pages from `http` and to `https` from `https`, just leave off the protocol.

```
<a href="//example.com/foo.html">
```

is a perfectly valid link with a *protocol-relative* URL, and if it appears in an `http` page, then the protocol will be set to `http`, and if it appears in an `https` page then the protocol will be set to `https`.

[RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) which defines URL references and resolution of relative URLs has these examples:

> Within a representation with a well defined base URI of
>
> ```
>   http://a/b/c/d;p?q
> ```
>
> a relative reference is transformed to its target URI as follows.
>
> ```
> ...
> "//g"           =  "http://g"
> ...
> ```

Comment: I'd rather not update all of my links to include a domain. How is a MITM possible when I'm using two different cookies with two different ID's, and one of them is encrypted? How would I store a "hint" that the user is logged in?

Comment: @mistermartin, If your links are path relative then they already assume the current protocol.

Comment: @mistermartin, cookies without the [secure flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) set will be visible on `http` pages, so to set a hint, when you set your other auth cookies on login/logout, just also set an insecure cookie that is just a boolean logged-in/not-logged-in.